# Getting "undefined" from error.email when trying to link multiple auth providers in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm trying to link multiple auth providers to one account using `firebase`.  The user is trying to create an account with the same address as the Google OAuth account which is already on `firebase`.

```js
firebase
.auth()
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(async result => {
    if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
        firebase
            .database()
            .ref('/users/' + result.user.uid)
            .set({
                email: email,
                profile_picture: image,
                first_name: firstName,
                last_name: lastName,
                created_at: Date.now()
            })
            .then(snapshot => console.log("do something"))
    } else {
        firebase
            .database()
            .ref('/users/' + result.user.uid)
            .update({
                last_logged_in: Date.now()
            })
            .then(snapshot => console.log("do something"))
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use' || error.code === 'auth/credential-already-in-use' || error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        const pendingCred = error.credential
        const email = error.email
        firebase
            .auth()
            .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
            .then(methods => {
                switch (methods[0]) {
                    case 'password':
                        // email and password logic
                        break;
                    case 'facebook.com':
                        // facebook logic
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            })
        return;
    }
})
```

The problem is I'm getting the proper error message:

> [Error: The email address is already in use by another account.]

and the proper `error.code`:

> auth/email-already-in-use

but, `pendingCred` or `error.email` come back `undefined`.

**Update**
I took the advise and tried the following:

```js
firebase.auth()
    .EmailAuthProvider
    .credential(email, password)
    .then(result => console.log("result", result))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

I'm getting the error:

> [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.default.auth().EmailAuthProvider.credential')]

Comment: What does the `error` object look like?

Comment: `console.log(error)` only gives `The email address is already in use by another account.` although `console.log(error.code)` gives `auth/email-already-in-use`.

Comment: As far as I know the error does *not* contain the credential, and you instead you need to create the credentials with `var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);` as shown in the documentation on [linking accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account). Did you find the example with `error.credentials` somewhere else in the docs?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen found the example from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login#handling-account-exists-with-different-credential-errors

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for pointing that out, as I'd never seen it (yay for hidden blocks on the documentation). But as far as I can see that flow only works for linking Facebook to an existing provider. You are linking email to an existing provider, for which I only see examples with `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password)` to create the credentials.

Comment: I'm getting the `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.default.auth().EmailAuthProvider.credential')]` error when I use `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password)`.  I've updated it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `createuserwithEmailAndPassword` which does not contain `error.email` or `error.credential`. According to the documentation to get the error you can either use `error.message` or `error.code`:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
    alert('The password is too weak.');
  } else {
    alert(errorMessage);
  }
  console.log(error);
});
```

According to the documentation, the `error.email` and `error.credential` is used if you get the following error code:

```
auth/credential-already-in-use
auth/account-exists-with-different-credential
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#error-codes_5

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#sign-inwith-credential

Comment: Not sure how to properly implement `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password)` and I keep getting `[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_firebase.default.auth().EmailAuthProvider.credential')]`

Answer (score 1):

The email was in `error.customData.email` for me.